# Does Angular check for differences on static binding?

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

When using `OnPush` change detection strategy Angular checks for `@Input` values reference changes to mark the component as dirty. Does it also apply when the value is static?

Example A:

```html
<sub-component myText="Hello World"></sub-component>
```

Example B:

```html
<sub-component [myText]="'Hello World'"></sub-component>
```

Does Angular in `Example A` also checks for reference changes as it would do in `Example B`? Is there any difference in performance?